# SQL LITE DATABASE VIEW IN ANDROID PHONE

Tags: android, sqlite

**

### I know this is possible duplicate. But I would like to highlight that even after following all the available instructions, I haven't been able to solve the issue

**

Can anyone tell how to view local database created by my android application in my android phone.

I'm not using any AVD . I'm directly deploying the application in my phone only. So i'm not able to view the table structure and data which is stored in my phone.

I know how to view database using sql lite browser and retrieve the database created in my laptop itself. Can any one help me to find way to get the database file from my phone to my system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite a long process, I think..

Your phone must me rooted to see database files.

1. Goto root folder from your phone
2. From there navigate to data/data/"your package name"/databases
3. There you will find the database file
4. Copy that database file to external storage of your phone and from external storage to your computer.
5. Now download a Sqlite Database viewer for your computer's operating system and you can view your database in that.

Note: There is an add-on for Mozilla Firefox to view sqlite database you have to google that.

Comment: Dear Chordin4tion Thanks alot.....

Comment: I have done eith another way. Please have a look at https://github.com/thedathoudarya/AndroidDBvieweR on github. Its very helpfull